# Neo4J with Spring at my browser

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am new at NoSQL graphs databases. I am learning Neo4J with Java througth https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/.
How can I see my nodes that I created by Java at the http address http://localhost:7474/browser/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That guide uses an embedded Neo4j instance, which is accessible within the Java application. Specifically, this code:

```
@Bean
GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("accessingdataneo4j.db");
}
```

is creating an embedded Neo4j instance in the current working directory with the name `accessingdataneo4j.db`. To use the Neo4j Browser you'll need to run Neo4j Server. Follow the instructions [here](http://neo4j.com/download/) to download and install Neo4j.

If you are using the Mac or Windows desktop application you can select the location for the embedded database your created previously - just point the "Database Location" to the location of `accessingdataneo4j.db` that you created and start the server. Then you can access the Neo4j Browser at http://localhost:7474

[image]

If you are not using the desktop application you can set the location of the database directory in `conf/neo4j-server.properties`:

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=/path/to/accessingdataneo4j.db
```

Comment: thanks, it worked! I also need to uncomment allow_store_upgrade=true at neo4j.properties